# Avoid duplication in Rails validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two validations:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A(.+)@(aol|gmail|office365|outlook|verizon|yahoo)\.com\Z/i }, if: Proc.new { |user| user.imap_server.blank? }
validates :email, presence: true
validates :imap_server, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |user| user.email.present? && user.email_invalid? }


def email_invalid?
    self.email =~ /\A(.+)@(aol|gmail|office365|outlook|verizon|yahoo)\.com\Z/i
end
```

I show a user a form. It displays an `email` field but not `imap_server` field. If the value in `email` field does not match the specific regex, then I want to show them form again with the `imap_server` field present as well. If they enter a value for the `imap_server` field, then I no longer want to validate the regex of `email` field (although it must still be present).

The problem it feels like I am duplicating a validation. Both `email_invalid?` and the `validates :email, format: ...` do the same thing. How can I clean this up?

Comment: At least you could extract the regex to a local constant and reuse it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `validates :email, format: ...` with

```
validate :email_format

def email_format
  errors.add(:email, 'format invalid') if imap_server.blank? && email_invalid?
end
```

which is slightly more lines but lets you define the format validation in one place.

Comment: This never detects the 'format invalid' message when trying from the console and giving an invalid email.

Comment: Yes and it returns true, even if I use an email of 'info@abc.net'. However, the original way I have it in the question, it returns false.

Comment: And what's returned when you do `my_record.email_invalid?`  And `my_record.imap_server.blank?`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is you're trying to check the result of a validation (email_invalid?) while you're * still doing * the validations... you don't know what order the validations are going to be run (the order on the page is not something I'd trust)... so the best way to solve it is to just write all these things into a single validates method eg a quick-and-dirty way:

```
validates :email_or_imap_server

def email_or_imap_server
  email_valid = false # for scoping
  if email.present?
    # note: email validation via regex is harder than you think...
    # google it...
    email_valid = email.match(/#{VALID_EMAIL_FORMATS}/)
    if email_invalid
      errors.add(:email, "email invalid format should be...")
      errors.add(:imap_server, "email or imap-server must be present") unless imap_server.present?
    end
  else
    errors.add(:imap_server, "either email or imap-server must be present") unless imap_server.present?
  end
end
```

etc.

Note: the code above is almost certainly full of bugs and typos... don't copy/paste it almost certainly won't work and the logic doesn't exactly match that of your validations... but do something like this.